# BigCommerce, How to use new panel and snippet files with a custom page layout

Tags: templates, layout, product, bigcommerce

I am trying to create custom page layouts for each of the product types to have their own, so that I can have specific size charts for mens, womens, tops, bottoms, ect. I have created the new template, applied it to a single product, created a new productdetail panel that is a direct copy of the original and referenced it in my new product layout. As soon as I try to refence the new one my image and add to cart are gone. Is there something that I am missing about the BC template structure or referencing?

Comment: you can't create custom snippets. You can only do custom panels and layouts.

Comment: Thats weird that you cant create custom snippets though you can edit them. But I can't even get the custom panel to display properly, even if it is just a copy of the original. Is there another way using Java to accomplish this using the sku, or say first 6 digits of the sku?

Comment: Why when I change the panel productdetail to a custom panel do I lose all the images?

Comment: Because some panels or snippets can only be referenced within their original panel or layout. And you can't host java on the bc servers. This is a list of existing panels that can be called within a custom panel: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/store_wide_panels and the store wide variables that can be called: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/store_wide_variables

Comment: Thank you for all your help alyss, I am new to BC and trying to figure out the architecture, I even tried to take the entire code from a referenced panel and drop the code in, instead of being referenced to no avail. I guess I just dont get how it is referencing a page, and if I copy the same code to another page how it doesnt reference the same, is it the heirarchy that it is in the panel folder?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create custom page layouts in BigCommerce in Stencil.  You should use the Stencil CLI to test this work before deploying, but here are the steps:

1. Create custom directory and required folders.

   `mkdir templates/pages/custom 
   cd templates/pages/custom
   mkdir brand product category page`
2. update .stencil in theme home dir - to add the mapping for the new page layout for a single product:

`"customLayouts": {
        "brand": {}, 
        "category": {}, 
        "page": {}, 
        "product": {
             "product-size-chart": "/sample-that-software-guy-t-shirt/"
        }`

3. Restart stencil
   `stencil start`

You MUST restart `stencil` after modifying `.stencil`.

4. copy the default product page to your new page layout

`cp ./templates/pages/product.html templates/pages/custom/product/product-size-chart.html`

then copy the view html:

`cp templates/components/products/product-view.html templates/components/products/product-view-size-chart.html`

5. edit  `templates/pages/custom/product/product-size-chart.html`
   to point to `product-view-size-chart` instead of the default file (just product).

`<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        {{> components/products/product-view-size-chart schema=true}}`

then in `templates/components/products/product-view-size-chart.html`,
change inclusion of tabs file to 

            `{{> components/products/description-size-tabs}}`

6. create this new file: 
   `cp ./templates/components/products/description-tabs.html ./templates/components/products/description-size-tabs.html`

edit it and add the new tab you want: 

        `<li class="tab">
            <a class="tab-title" href="#tab-size-chart">{{lang 'products.size-chart'}}</a>
        </li>`

right above the warranty tab.

7. update `lang/en.json` to have the define for size-chart.
8. update `templates/components/products/description-size-tabs.html` to show the image

Once you have this all done and working locally with the CLI, bundle your theme and upload and activate it.  Then, edit the product where you want the new layout to be used, and go to Other details to set the template layout file to the new layout you have created.